# GeoServer CQL cross layer filtering: querySingle/queryCollection for non-geometry attribute return

Tags: geoserver, cql-filter, crossfilter

I have only been able to find examples where geometry attributes are returned from cross layer filtering functions, but the GeoServer documentation says:

> [A common use case is to extract a geometry-valued attribute, and then use the value(s) in a spatial predicate against a geometry attribute in the primary layer.](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html)

Which leads me to believe that it was intended to be used to return other data.

**I'm looking for examples of how that might be done in a CQL filter.**

---

I have attempted something like this:
http://localhost:8181/geoserver/test/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=test:layer1,test:layer2&styles=&bbox=-81.54053,41.61621,-77.33826,43.41248&width=768&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers&**cql_filter=INCLUDE;property2a=querySingle('test:layer1','property1b','property1a=123')**

Where only records in layer2 that have layer2.property2a = layer1.property1b are returned.

I get the exception: "Could not parse CQL filter list."

---

Similarly:
http://localhost:8181/geoserver/test/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=test:layer1,test:layer2&styles=&bbox=-81.54053,41.61621,-77.33826,43.41248&width=768&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers&**cql_filter=INCLUDE;property2a IN queryCollection('test:layer1','property1b','INCLUDE')**

Where the values of layer2 will only be returned if layer2.property2a has a value in the returned values from layer1.property1b